# Pass deeply nested element to function in JQuery

Tags: jquery

I have this form:

```
<form action="contact.php" method="post" id="contactform">
          <ol>
            <li>
              <label for="name">First Name * </label>
              <input id="name" name="name" class="text" />
            </li>
            <li>
              <label for="email">Your email * </label>
              <input id="email" name="email" class="text" />
            </li>
            <li>
              <label for="company">Company</label>
              <input id="company" name="company" class="text" />
            </li>
            <li>
              <label for="subject">Subject</label>
              <input id="subject" name="subject" class="text" />
            </li>
            <li>
              <label for="message">Message * </label>
              <textarea id="message" name="message" rows="6" cols="50"></textarea>
            </li>

            <li class="buttons">
              <input type="image" name="imageField" id="imageField" src="images/send.gif" />
            </li>
          </ol>
        </form>
```

This javascript function that does some basic validation:

```
function validateRequired(field,alerttxt) {
    with (field) {
        if (value==null||value=="") {
            alert(alerttxt);
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

And this script (written with jquery) to intercept the submit event

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    $('#contactform').submit(function(){
        ...
    });
});
```

The problem is that, inside the last script I want to call `validateRequired` passing each required input/textarea (namely: `name`, `email` and `message`) as first parameter.

I tried like this:

```
validateRequired($('#name'));
```

but it doesn't work.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was inspired by Jeff Vyduna solution, but solved it on my own.

```
$('#contactform').submit(function(){
            var submit = true;

        $('#contactform *.required').each(function(){
                if(!validateRequired(this, this.id + ' is required'))
                {
                    submit = false;
                    return false;
                }
        });

        return submit;
});
```

Obviousy the input fields (including the `textarea`) have to be of class `required`.

Comment: hmm i started to do it my self to when i found this: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation

Answer (score 2):

I would first add a class to each required input.

```
  <li>
    <label for="subject">Subject</label>
    <input id="subject" name="subject" class="text required" />
  </li>
```

Then select all the required inputs with one jQuery selector and iterate through them.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  $('#contactform').submit(function(){
    $('#contactform input.required').each(function(){
      validateRequired(this, this.attr('name') + ' is required');
    });
  });
});
```

While this spits out generic alerts like "subject is required", hopefully you can use this iterator pattern to implement an even better user experience, perhaps by highlighting the required text fields with a different background color.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  $('#contactform').submit(function(){
    $('#contactform input.required').each(function(){
      this.addClass('error');
      alert('The fields highlighted in red are required');
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: the first solution partially works. I had to chage `this.attr('name')` to `this.id`. Also it doesn't validate `message` since it is a `textarea`. Any other hint?